# browser based xslt wysiwyg editor

Tags: xml, xslt, editor, wysiwyg, browser-based

I am trying to find a browser-based wysiwyg xslt editor. It needs to be able to take an xml document as the source file, along with an xslt stylesheet - allow the xslt stylesheet to be edited, and then show the resulting html output.

Does a browser-based tool like this exist? I have seen a few desktop-based editors whilst doing Google searches but, so far, no browser-based ones.

Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: As much as I hate w3schools (http://w3fools.com/) they do have one section with an XML and XSLT editor that sounds like what you want (it outputs html and the browser renders it): http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

Comment: Sounds like a very strange requirement. Why browser-based? What additional value does this bring, compared with non-barowser based true editors and IDEs? What I can see immediately is that there would be security limitations, which don't exist for the non-browser-based editors.

Comment: Browser-based so that our clients can edit their html pages which are produced from an xml/xsl transformation.